# Trying user inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-input

```
person = {
   "name": "Luca",
   "surname": "Rossi",
   "age": 25
}

operations = ("adding", "modifying", "deleting", "read person", "exit")

def start():
     operation = input("What you wanna do? ")
     if operation == operations[0]:
         x = input("Add a key:value separated by a comma: ")
         add(x.split(","))
     elif operation == operations[1]:
         x = input("Select a key:value and modify it: ")
         modify(x.split(":"))
     elif operation == operations[2]:
         x = input("Select a key:value and delete it: ")
         delete(x)
     elif operation == operations[3]:
         print(person)
     elif operation == operation[4]:
         exit()
     

def add(param):
    key= param[0]
    value= param[1]
    person[key] = value
    print(person)

def modify(param):
    key = param[0]
    value = param[1]
    person[key] = value
    print(person)

def delete(param):
    key = param
    if key in person:
       del person[key]
       print(person)
    else:
       print(f"The key '{key}' does not exist.")


while True:        
   start()
```

Why deleting isn't working? Adding and modifying were good as I wrote them. I'm trying different things for deleting, but no one it's ok.

Also tried pop, remove and del, but I'm a beginner and I'm not understanding why it isn't working.
The first 2 functions were easy for me...
Any help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Your code is working fine when I try running it. What exactly are you expecting it to do that it isn't doing?

Comment: Why does the input message state, that one should enter key **and** value when we just want to delete a key? The `delete` function doesn't expect a value. Unrelated: Don't use [`exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit). It's not meant to be used in programs.

Comment: @Matthias  Yeah i tried to run it some more times and magically, after few times without changing it, it worked. Related to the another comment, why exit isn't meant to be used in programs?

Comment: @Yes `exit` is for the interactive interpreter shell. Read the [documentation of `exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#exit). [`sys.exit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exit) is a different thing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue with the delete function in your code is related to how you're passing the input for deletion. In the delete function, you are passing the entire input (x) as a single parameter, but the input function returns a string, and you want to split it into key and value.

Here's the corrected version of the delete function:

```
def delete(param):
    key = param[0].strip()  # Strip to remove any leading/trailing whitespaces
    if key in person:
        del person[key]
        print(person)
    else:
        print(f"The key '{key}' does not exist.")
```

Now, when you call delete(x), it will correctly split the input string and use the first part as the key for deletion. Additionally, the strip() method is used to remove any leading or trailing whitespaces from the key.

For example, if you input "name" for deletion, it will correctly delete the "name" key from the dictionary.

Here's how the corrected delete function works:

```
x = input("Select a key to delete: ")
delete(x.split(":"))
```

Enter the key (e.g., "name"), and it should delete the corresponding entry from the person dictionary.

Comment: i tried it and it's the same result as mine, may it could be useful for more specific cases. Thank you anyway